# Meta-analysis for multiple outcomes with random effects model

Tags: r, meta-analysis

```
library(metafor)
dat <- get(data(dat.berkey1998))
V <- bldiag(lapply(split(dat[,c("v1i", "v2i")], dat$trial), as.matrix))
res <- rma.mv(yi, V, mods = ~ outcome - 1, random = ~ outcome | trial, struct="UN", data=dat, method="ML")
print(res, digits=3)

> dat
   trial           author year ni outcome      yi     vi    v1i    v2i
1      1 Pihlstrom et al. 1983 14      PD  0.4700 0.0075 0.0075 0.0030
2      1 Pihlstrom et al. 1983 14      AL -0.3200 0.0077 0.0030 0.0077
3      2    Lindhe et al. 1982 15      PD  0.2000 0.0057 0.0057 0.0009
4      2    Lindhe et al. 1982 15      AL -0.6000 0.0008 0.0009 0.0008
5      3   Knowles et al. 1979 78      PD  0.4000 0.0021 0.0021 0.0007
6      3   Knowles et al. 1979 78      AL -0.1200 0.0014 0.0007 0.0014
7      4  Ramfjord et al. 1987 89      PD  0.2600 0.0029 0.0029 0.0009
8      4  Ramfjord et al. 1987 89      AL -0.3100 0.0015 0.0009 0.0015
9      5    Becker et al. 1988 16      PD  0.5600 0.0148 0.0148 0.0072
10     5    Becker et al. 1988 16      AL -0.3900 0.0304 0.0072 0.0304
```

I am trying to understand this example documented [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:berkey1998). Each study has 2 correlated outcomes (PD and AL). And the goal of this analysis is to estimate a combined effect size fo PD, and to estimate a combined effect size for AL, correct?

In the following forest plot:[image]

What exactly are the grey diamonds overlapping the effect size & CI for each study? And why is there no combined effect at the bottom of the forest plot? In my mind I was expecting 2 forest plots: 1 for the combined effect size of PD, and one of the combined effect size of AL, am I understanding the analysis correctly?

```
res2

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 10; method: ML)

Variance Components: 

outer factor: trial   (nlvls = 5)
inner factor: outcome (nlvls = 2)

            estim    sqrt  k.lvl  fixed  level
tau^2.1    0.0261  0.1617      5     no     AL
tau^2.2    0.0070  0.0837      5     no     PD

    rho.AL  rho.PD    AL  PD
AL       1  0.6992     -  no
PD  0.6992       1     5   -

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 8) = 128.2267, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 1,2): 
QM(df = 2) = 155.7733, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

           estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
outcomeAL   -0.3379  0.0798  -4.2368  <.0001  -0.4943  -0.1816  ***
outcomePD    0.3448  0.0495   6.9721  <.0001   0.2479   0.4418  ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

A quick look at the summary of `res` shows me an estimate of AL and PD. Are these the combined effect sizes for AL, and PD, respectively? And what exactly does `mods = ~ outcome - 1` do?

Comment: In a model with a moderator there can be no overall effect.

Comment: I see. So can I interpret the estimate of `outcomeAL` as the overall effect of AL across all 5 studies? And similarly for `outcomePD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the values given for `outcomeAL` and `outcomePD` are the estimated average effects (in this case, mean differences) for the two outcomes.

By using `mods = ~ outcome - 1`, you get the two estimated average effects directly. If we had used `mods = ~ outcome`, we would get the estimated average effect for outcome `AL` and then a coefficient that is the *difference* (i.e., contrast) between the estimated average effect for outcome `AL` and outcome `PD`.

The gray diamonds/polygons in the forest plot show the predicted effects (i.e., fitted values) for each study. That is what is automatically shown when drawing a forest plot based on a model with moderator variables. In this example, the fitted values are just the values given for `outcomeAL` and `outcomePD` (so, for "studies" 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9, the value for `outcomePD`; for "studies" 2, 4, 6, 8, and 19, the value for `outcomeAL`). In this case, it probably would make things clearer by not drawing the gray polygons (use `addfit=FALSE`) and instead drawing two summary polygons at the bottom of the forest plot (this can be done using the `addpoly()` function).

Comment: Thank you. May I ask by specifying `mods = ~ outcome`, are we performing meta-regression? What's the difference between meta-regressing on the `outcome` variable vs. meta-analysis of bivariate outcomes?

Comment: I think you are drawing some kind of strange dichotomy between "meta-regression" and "meta-analysis of bivariate outcomes". With `mods = ~ outcome` (or `mods = ~ outcome - 1`), we are allowing the estimated average effects to differ for the two outcomes. That is part of what one typically does when meta-analyzing two different outcomes. And yes, one can also think of this as "meta-regression".